# ¿ como puedo actualizar o refrescar los datos que tengo en un jlist?

Tags: java, java-swing

tengo un jlist que cuando se abre el programa se le insertan datos de un base de datos(sqlite), pero cuando presiono un botón(Agregar Proyecto) este debería guardar un dato en la base de datos y luego refrescar el jlist, el dato se guarda correctamente pero el jlist no se esta actualizando.

Este es mi Jframe Form principal

```
public class Tareas extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Tareas() {
        initComponents();
        jlistProyectos.setModel(consultas.traerProyectos(jlistProyectos));
    }
    
    private void botonAgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        AgregarProyecto a = new AgregarProyecto();
        a.setVisible(true);

        consultas.traerProyectos(jlistProyectos);
    }    

    public JList<String> jlist(){
        return jlistProyectos;
    }
    
    private Consultas consultas = new Consultas();
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton botonActualizar;
    private javax.swing.JButton botonAgregar;
    private javax.swing.JButton botonAgregar1;
    private javax.swing.JButton botonEliminar;
    private javax.swing.JButton botonMostrar;
    private javax.swing.JButton botonRefrescar;
    private javax.swing.JButton botonSalir;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jlistProyectos;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Este Jframe Form se abre cuando se presiona el botón `botonAgregar`

```
public class AgregarProyecto extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public AgregarProyecto() {
        initComponents();
    }     

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String nombreProyecto = cajaTituloProyecto.getText();
        
        if(nombreProyecto.isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Por Favor agregue un titulo a su proyecto");
        }else{
            Proyecto proyecto = new Proyecto(nombreProyecto);
            consulta.agregarProyecto(proyecto);
            
            super.dispose();
            
        }
    }                                        

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AgregarProyecto().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    

    private Tareas tarea = new Tareas();
    private Consultas consulta = new Consultas();
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField cajaTituloProyecto;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

y en esta clase tengo las consultas

```
public class Consultas {
    Conexion cc = new Conexion();
    Connection cn = cc.conectar();

    
    public void agregarProyecto(Proyecto proyecto){
        try{
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Proyectos VALUES (?)");
            pst.setString(1, proyecto.getTituloProyecto());
            pst.executeUpdate();       
            pst.close();            
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    
    public DefaultListModel traerProyectos(JList jlist){
        DefaultListModel modelo = new DefaultListModel();
        ResultSet resultado = null;
        try{
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT TituloProyecto FROM Proyectos");
            resultado = pst.executeQuery();
        
            while(resultado.next()){
                modelo.addElement(resultado.getString("TituloProyecto"));
                //System.out.println(resultado.getString("TituloProyecto"));
                jlist.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            }

            pst.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }    
        return modelo;
    }
    
}
```

no se que estaré haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtienes la lista actualizada pero no se la mandas al componente.
De hecho `traerProyectos` debería regresar un `List<String>` y no debería recibir el `JList` ¿Qué tiene que ver el color de primer plano con la obtención de datos? Al "inyectarle" datos a la lista estás mezclando indecentemente vista con modelo.

Deberías obtener el modelo en lugar de crear uno nuevo, limpiarlo y volver a llenarlo a partir de lo obtenido; el componente al detectar el cambio en el modelo actualiza la vista automáticamente.

```
    private void botonAgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        AgregarProyecto a = new AgregarProyecto();
        a.setVisible(true);
        
        DefaultListModel modelo = (DefaultListModel)jlistProyectos.getModel();
        modelo.removeAllElements();
        for( String s : consultas.traerProyectos() )
            modelo.addElement( s );
    }
```

Comment: lo que pasa con esta solución es que cuando me trae el modelo, me lo limpia e inmediatamente me vuelve a insertar los datos, entonces no espera a que se agregue un nuevo dato a la base de datos, por eso la actualización queda igual, debería esperar hasta que se presione el botón de la nueva ventana `a` y luego insertar datos.

Comment: ahora me funciona pero tuve que dejar public y static el jlist (no sabia eso) y le pase el código al segundo frame(AgregarProyecto) por que en el primero me actualizaba apenas presionaba el botón.

Answer (score 0):

Después de hacer la inserción, cargas los datos de la base de datos en un nuevo *DefaultListModel*, pero en ningún momento se lo asignas al *JList*; el *JList* no se da de ningún cambio porque el *TableModel* que tiene no ha cambiado.

Lo más sencillo es sencillamente hacer *jlist.setModel(modelo)* después del *while* del *resultado*.